# How to fix 'APK is using CAMERA permissions that require a privacy policy error in play console?

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, google-play

I'm setting my flutter app to upload on play console but it shows error- "Your APK or Android App Bundle is using permissions that require a privacy policy: (android.permission.CAMERA)."

I am tried to solve this problem. I am already using permission for camera in my manifest file. How can i solve this problem ?
[image: Play error screenshot]

main/manifest file :

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.subidhacustomermobileappv2">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

  <application
      android:name=".Application"
      android:label="Example"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
      <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTop"
          android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
          android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>

          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
           This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
      <meta-data
          android:name="flutterEmbedding"
          android:value="2" />

      <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
      <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />

      <service
          android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
          android:exported="false"/>
      <receiver
          android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
          android:exported="false"/>
      <receiver
          android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
          android:enabled="false">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>

  </application>
</manifest>
```

pubspec.yaml file is :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  json_annotation: ^3.0.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.7+2
  flutter_local_notifications: ^1.4.3
  rxdart: ^0.24.0
  provider: ^4.0.5+1
  easy_localization: ^2.3.2
  # double_back_to_close_app: ^1.2.0
  double_back_to_close_app: ^2.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.6+4
  photo_view: ^0.9.2
  http: ^0.12.1
  dio: ^3.0.9
  fluttertoast: ^4.0.1
  cached_network_image: ^2.2.0+1
  expandable: ^4.1.4
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.4.0
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.3
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.22+1
  sslcommerz: ^0.0.1
  toast: ^0.1.5
  dropdown_search: 0.4.4
  android_intent: ^0.3.7+3
  table_calendar: ^2.2.3
  smooth_star_rating: 1.1.1
  url_launcher: ^5.7.1
  crisp: ^0.1.3
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_database: ^3.1.3
  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.2
  intl: ^0.16.1
  clipboard_manager: ^0.0.4
  android_alarm_manager: 0.4.5+14
  device_apps: ^1.2.0
  camera: ^0.5.8+17
```

Comment: please accept my answer if it's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add privacy policy for the store.
Go to Google Play Console, Select Store preference > App content. Under "Privacy Policy"  add a privacy policy URL.
NB: This url should be public. It could be from any website. If you app has website then use form that website but if it doesn't then you may use it from 3rd party.

Comment: This solution is very useful. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your app's manifest.xml having these permission to access information from your's device but you don't have privacy policy link while submitting on the play store. so you getting this warning.